# What is the easiest way to produce this type of table/diagram?

Tags: tables, diagrams

I want to produce a table like this:

[image]

is this even doable with tables or do I need to use a diagram library?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Imho, this is doable using a `table`. However, the nature of your content rather suggest to use a diagram. Have you tried with `tikz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I first followed Peter's suggestion and tried it with tables. Unfortunately I also use `booktabs` in my document and apparently it doesn't like vertical lines.

I then moved on to `tikz` as suggested by ebo and I'm quite happy with the result:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center, text width=6cm, line width=0.75pt]
    \node (client) [draw, rectangle] {
        \textbf{Client} \\
        text, text 
    };
    \node (arrow) [below = 0 of client] {$\Updownarrow$};
    \node (stack) [draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3, below = 0 of arrow] {
        \textbf{BaaS} \\
        text, text 
        \nodepart{second}
        \textbf{PaaS} \\
        text, text
        \nodepart{third}
        \textbf{IaaS} \\
        text, text
     };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Please provide *complete* code in your posts. (And, yes, I know the other answer doesn't. But three wrongs do not a right make.)

Answer (score 2):

The following sets the boxes and vertical construction as a set of `tabular`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,array}

\newcommand{\diagrambox}[2][15em]{%
  \fcolorbox{blue}{white}{%
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
      #2
    \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \diagrambox{\textbf{Cloud Clients} \\
                Web browser, mobile app, thin client, terminal, emulator, \ldots} \\
    $\Updownarrow$ \\
    \diagrambox{\textbf{SaaS} \\
                CRM, Email, virtual desktop, communication, games, \ldots} \\[-\fboxrule]
    \diagrambox{\textbf{PaaS} \\
                Execution runtime, database, web server, development tools, \ldots} \\[-\fboxrule]
    \diagrambox{\textbf{IaaS} \\
                Virtual machines, servers, storage, load balancers, network, \ldots}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

`\diagrambox[<width>]{<stuff>}` can be adjusted to fit wider content via the optional first argument. Default is `15em`.

Answer (score 1):

Take 2 tables and one image. Pack it into a minipage environment. Its very simple.

Just my opinion.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to answer questions without code!